# Still no way to add a simple email background image that works in Outlook and OWA?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, vml

Is it true that it is still not possible to add a simple background image to email that shows up in most mail clients, at least in Outlook.exe and OWA (aka Outlook.com)?

I've tried [most](https://backgrounds.cm/) of the typical [hacks](https://elasticemail.com/blog/transactional_email/email-rendering-issues-in-outlook-and-hacks-to-save-the-day#:%7E:text=Input%20the%20below%20code%20in%20the%20%3Cbody%3E%20tag%20of%20your%20HTML%20for%20the%20background%20image%20to%20cover%20the%20entire%20email%20window) already, including various ones with VML, but none have worked (in Outlook 365 as of 2021).

The only thing that works within Outlook itself is the page background image as known from Microsoft Word:

[image: Microsoft Word/Outlook background Image]

But of course that doesn't show up in any other mail client, not even OWA.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question that can be easily self-answered by simply reading the documentations/references such as [can I email this?](https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=background-image)

Comment: That link has no information whatsoever about *how* to do what I have asked. Also, the information at the link is incorrect, because there are hacks for bg-image for both Outlook.exe and Outlook.com

Answer (score 1):

Outlook uses Word as a rendering engine for message bodies. And Word considers unsupported cascading style sheet properties to be unknown properties:

- background-attachment
- background-image
- background-position
- background-repeat

Instead, you can use embedded images (hidden attachments) in the message bodies by suing the `cid` attribute in the HTML markup.

Comment: Thanks, I was going to use embedded images anyway -- but how does that solve the problem of actually placing the image as background-image?